# how to inejct a maven artifact from nexus to a docker container

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins, dockerfile, nexus

I'am working on implementing a CI/CD pipeline with jenkins as an autimation tool, maven for build, nexus as artifacts repository and docker for deployement.
 So my problem is that when ever I try to deploy a ".jar" file from nexus to a docker container, the docker image is built but when I want to run it I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile ,junit-1.2.jar
```

And this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
WORKDIR /
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre
RUN update-alternatives --config java
RUN update-alternatives --config javac
RUN apt-get install curl
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
RUN curl -u login:passwd -o junit-1.2.jar "nexus repository URL/junit-1.2.jar" -L

ENTRYPOINT java -jar ,junit-1.2.jar
```

Thank you for your help, and I'm open to any better solution to do this.

Comment: I think you only have a typo: ,junit-1.2.jar -> the comma

Comment: I removed the comma, rebuilt and run it but still getting the same error message 

**Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile junit-1.2.jar**

Comment: Junit seems not to be a runable jar.

Comment: It seems the problem will be solved once you get this question answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610058/how-to-fix-invalid-or-corrupt-jarfile

Comment: @PauloPedroso exactly, I tried to figure out what the problem is, and I noticed that the Jarfile itself is not runnable, so I posted that question