# how to fix invalid or corrupt Jarfile?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, executable-jar

I am working on a simple java project 'Hello world!'. So after creating my code  I built it and created the Jarfile using maven:

```
mvn clean install package
```

So my problem is when ever I try to run the executable Jarfile I get the 
following error message:

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile junit-1.2.jar
```

this is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>


<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>


 <dependencies>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13-beta-1</version>
   </dependency>

     </dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>hello</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

And this is my MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: jenkins
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.6.0
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_191
Main-Class: hello
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Something is wrong, is it your actual error and actual pom file. Error says junit-1.2 but your pom file says 4.13-beta-1. And hope your main class is hello not Hello (and not in package)

Comment: thank you for your notes:
"4.13-beta-1" mentioned in POM file is for the J-unit (for unit test) dependency, my bad for giving the same name to the project.
And yes the main class is hello not Hello, but it is in a package called junit.

Comment: Even though your package is version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and not 1.2.

Comment: To build my code with maven I'm using a build automation tool, 'Jenkins', and I'm putting the Jar files in a private artifacts repository, Nexus. I don't know why exactely the Jar file is getting the 1.2 and not the 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, but it's getting the "1.2" tag from the configuration in Nexus

Comment: @AbidiTaha Edit question and add information about jenkins and how the jar file is transfered from jenkins and where and how you or (automate process) executing the jar file?